# WPF datagrid detecting whether the last row is visited or not?

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a WPF Datagrid in my application and as there are more that 25000 rows should be loaded I have created a custom pagination working with shortcut keys.

Now I am wondering if there is any way to detect whether the last row of current page is visited so I can load next page and append it to my Datagrid without any shortcut keys or click?

Update:
I have added an event to vertical scrollbar for datagrid, and still can't find a way to determine whether the last row has brought to view or not?

Any suggestions?

Comment: When you say "visited", do you mean brought into View?  If yes, then [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/658258/wpf-datagrid-check-visible-rows) may help.

Comment: @BrianS, Yes I meant brought to view.
Thanks for the link, but still can't replicate this solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the trick:

following event helped me out:

```
> void dgScrollbar_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs
> e)
>         {
>             if (((System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer)(sender)).ContentVerticalOffset
> + e.ViewportHeight == e.ExtentHeight)
>             {
>                 LoadNextPageBinding_Executed(null, null);
>             }
>         }
```